# Azure Functions how to get a new local.settings.json?

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions, .net-6.0

What I have been doing for some time now when using Azure Functions is to setup a `local.settings.json` file with where I configure settings like, ConnectionStrings, specific API's endpoints etc.

In the end I go to `portal.azure.com -> MyFunctions -> Configuration -> Application Settings` and add all my settings over there.

The thing is over time we get quite some settings that need to be configured, so the `local.settings.json` file grows as well.

But, suppose you are new and you have to work with this Functions project for the first time. How do you easily get that `local.settings.json` file without being depended on a co-worker that coincidentally has the file on his local drive?

So since you don't commit the `local.settings.json` file, how does one know what settings need to be configured?

Is it really the only option to take a look at the settings in portal.azure.com and re-create the `local.settings.json` file from scratch? Or is there a better way to solve this issue?

Comment: I am not sure what is the solution. But normally what happen that there is a development version and developer check in with code if there is any change. And for higher environment it get replaced using the CI/CD pipeline.

Answer (score 5):

Run this from inside your local function app folder. It will create your local.settings.json file if it does not exist.

```
func azure functionapp fetch-app-settings <function app name>
```

Comment: I can confirm this works well. Thanks.

Comment: Worked for me as well. This also resolved lingering issues I had updating a v3 netcore3.1 azure function to v4 net6 and getting it to deploy properly via Azure's generated GitHub deployment action. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for being late, but I wanted to leave here a script I have done to get the configs of a Function app or it slots (I needed to work with slots), format them with the local.settings.json file format and also resolve the keyvault values all at the same time.

[I leave it here](https://github.com/Makishi-UY/fetch-azure-function-local-settings) in case this helps somebody.

My problem was that this gets the settings in another format

```
az webapp config appsettings list
```

And this does not give me the configs of a specific slot

```
func azure functionapp fetch-app-settings
```

I just uploaded it in Github as I found this thread. Sorry for the poor Powershell standards as I am not an expert in PS scripting.